# jQuery Change Background Color If

Tags: jquery

I was wondering how I can change background color with selectors. This is my code:

```
<div id="example">
    <select id="worked">
        <option id="green">Green</option>
        <option id="orange">orange</option>
    </select>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    var n = $("select option:selected")

    if (n == "green") {
        $("body").css("background", "green");
    } 
    else {
        $("body").css("background", "orange");
    }

});
</script>
```

So If I select green, it wont show nor orange. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't you want to bind this via the change event on the select element?

Comment: Why not get the value of the select element, `var color = $('#worked').val();` - no need to find the option which is selected like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This :

```
var n = $("select option:selected")
```

returns an element, and not the value, that would be :

```
var n = $("select option:selected").val();
```

which can also be done as :

```
var n = $("select").val();
```

as the selects value will be the same as the selected option,
but you probably want to hook onto the change event of the select, like so :

```
$("select").on('change', function() {
    $("body").css("background", this.value);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/XZdbK/)

**EDIT:**

with a condition setting the background to orange for anything other than green:

```
$("select").on('change', function() {
    if (this.value == 'green') {
        $("body").css("background", 'green');
    }else{
        $("body").css("background", 'orange');
    }
});
```

or :

```
$("select").on('change', function() {
    $("body").css("background", this.value == 'green'?'green':'orange');
});
```

Comment: Works! IS there a way with the IF Statement?

Comment: Thanks but can you do it like with select id? It feels more understandable to me because I would like to change selects.

Comment: You can do it with any selector you choose, for the ID, just replace `select` with `#worked`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$('#worked').change(function() { /* triggered when select box changed. */ });
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/wNhP3/)